# Xalan call user Java function

Tags: java, call, xalan

I try several test and i search any solution but I can't find anything.
I have to call my Java function in a XSLT. My last solution, that I believe is the best is the following, I declare my class with

Xalan:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
    xmlns:printAnno="StampaAnnoUtil"
    extension-element-prefixes="printAnno">

<xalan:component prefix="printAnno"
        elements="isStampaAnno" functions="isStampaAnno">
        <xalan:script lang="javaclass" src="java:it.dpe.common.util.StampaAnnoUtil"/>
    </xalan:component>
```

I call my function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="printAnno:isStampaAnno()"/>
```

and I get an error directly in my Oxygen editor and if I try to compile the report I get:

> fo:page-sequence is missing child elements.
>
> F XPath syntax error at char 24 on line 652 in {printAnno:isStampaAnno()}:
>       Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {StampaAnnoUtil}isStampaAnno().

Where is the fault?
The XSLl is in a DB but when I transform it is in my path.

Comment: Did you register your jar file with Oxygen as an XSLT processor extension?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to register your jar file with Oxygen. The implementation of your function must be known to it. A definition such as the one you posted acts like glue, but you still need to provide what you want glued together. Try the following (or something similar, it's been ages since I used Oxygen):

- Click on the "Configure Validation Scenario" button from the toolbar
- Check the "Use custom validation scenario" box
- Click on the "New" button to create a new scenario
- Click on the "Add" button
- Selects the "Engine type" to specify your processor, Xalan for instance
- Click on the Extensions button
- Click on "Add" then browse for your jar files
- Click "Ok" on all dialogs

[Source](http://osdir.com/ml/editors.oxygen.user/2007-08/msg00015.html)